# Is there an alternate version of Tarkovsky's "The Sacrifice"?

Tags: alternate-version, the-sacrifice

I watched "The Sacrifice" on YouTube.  The credits showed the original actors, so this was not a remake.  Yet it did not have the famous fixed-camera burning-house scene.  In this version the camera panned around on and off the house as it burned.  I know I saw the original version many years ago where the camera did not move for several minutes.  What gives?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what your question is. Are you saying that in one version, the camera is fixed on the house while in another version, the camera pans around the house but is not fixed. And you wan't to know why in the 2nd version this choice of cinematography & editing was done? Is that your question?

Comment: Based on [**Wikipedia's detail**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sacrifice#Filming) I think it likely that the OP's memory is faulty and no such **absolute** fixed camera shot exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no alternate version, only the one you saw with the camera panning around on and off the burning house.

Comment: Unable to find corroboration for (a) my interpretation of descriptions I have read (b) my memory, I must conclude I have misinterpreted them and generated a false memory to support this, a discouraging result.  Sorry for wasting your time. If I knew how to delete this question I would have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternate version, the one you saw is the only version.

I believe you are mixing this scene in The Sacrifice with the burning house scene in The Mirror which has a fixed-camera shot: [image: The Mirror (1975)]