# Are there two major versions of the Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer TV special?

Tags: alternate-version, rudolph-rednosed-reindeer

There are two versions of the Rudolph TV special, right? The original in which the would-be elf dentist yanks all the monster's teeth (really nasty), and the politically correct version where the dentist merely fixes a toothache (nice).

I ask because I participated in a forum a few years ago in which some really annoying and arrogant members insisted the toothache version couldn't possibly exist, merely because they hadn't seen it, even though several other members said they had. (I have seen both versions.)  I was wondering if consensus has been reached yet among the amateur TV historians who inhabit these discussion groups and the two-version story is now settled fact.

As a matter of history, the toothache version was introduced after a few years of the yank version, presumably because yanking all his teeth violated the monster's right to be who he is.  I don't know how many years the toothache version held sway, but then, for some reason unknown to me, the network went back to the yank version, which explains how the naysayers could have missed the toothache version.

Comment: There might be a real question in here, but as worded it sounds like a rant, not a question. Voted to close as Unclear.

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/MandelaEffect/comments/7jl5oc/rudolph_the_rednosed_reindeer_1964/

Comment: @Paulie_D presumably this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_(TV_special)

Comment: I do suggest you edit your question to specify that this is indeed the TV show you are referring to and I suggest you remove the reason why you are asking as it comes across as a bit of a rant, and doesn't really add much to the question.

Comment: *"As a matter of history"* - Really? - **citation required**.

Comment: What Rudolph special? The one in the title "Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer".(original release 1964)

Comment: @GendoIkari seems there is an answer

Comment: What is my question? In the view of this forum's members, is it now settled fact that there exist these two versions?

Comment: @FernDalquist "In the view of this forum's members" is the issue. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, which means that the "views" of the members is irrelevant to a good answer. Simply reframing the question as "does this other version exist?" would be much better. The title as currently edited makes a good question.

Comment: I confess I don't understand.  Members supply answers (sometimes).  Members are not omniscient.  Therefore their answers reflect their views.  What am I missing?

Comment: While it's true that personal bias is impossible to avoid, a good answer will do its best to avoid it. In a general discussion forum, people could post things like "Yeah, I remember that scene being that way as well!" and it would be a fine post. But an "answer" like that would be very poorly received here. A good answer will include sources backing up what should be presented as objective fact.

Comment: OK let me try again. I really have two questions.  Are there the two versions I have outlined?  Is it accepted fact that there are these two versions.  Maybe the 2nd q can't be answered here because it requires not a knowledge of TV but rather of what people are saying, broadly speaking.

Comment: @FernDalquist This sites members answers Qs as best we can by supplying sources/facts and sometimes expert opinion/speculation, but we can't begin to do that until we know what you are asking. So if you want to know if there are two versions of a production (perhaps like a directors cut vs an extended cut) then that would be your question! Then some of us may answer usually with links and block text from a good source or two (pending on the Q's ask). However if there would be two versions and you just wanted *opinion only on them, then this site is not the place for that.

Comment: In your case it seems you are asking for a consensus about ametures taking something you allege factual (you didn't provide any sources) as fact to be able to prove to others that it is so? The best way to do that using this site is to prove that both films exist and/or ask, after you prove that, if there is evidence to support the "political correct" argument as the reason for the new version. Then if any of us know/find it and source it, you always can link the site and Q to wherever you want. You may not be able to change the minds of some, but at least you have a place that sourced it.

Comment: I have to confess, judging from your comments, you don't seem to be asking a genuine good-faith question. You seem to have already made up your mind that there are two versions, and the only answer you will accept is the one that says that, regardless of whether it actually offers proof beyond "yes, I remember it too".

Comment: I must also say, considering how readily you were willing to accept that you had misremembered [Tarkovsky's "The Sacrifice"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93389/is-there-an-alternate-version-of-tarkovskys-the-sacrifice), you seem alarmingly *un*willing to accept the possibility that the same may apply here.

Comment: Request re-open: I found a book reference, DIane Werts' "Christmas on Television", which, of course, itself could be wrong. I've also found another book reference that suggests the toothache, but doesn't state it outright.

Comment: @BarryCarter It's also worth noting that the monster having a toothache, and the dentist yanking all his teeth out, are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

Comment: There is a clip on Adult Swim's *Robot Chicken* where Hermie yanks out **one** of the Abominable Snowman's teeth but then decides to be a baker

Comment: The only big change was the song "We're a Couple of Misfits" was replaced by "Fame and Fortune" when Rudolph and Hermey meet for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Although there are multiple edits/cuts of the 1964 Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer Christmas special, most likely this particular difference in memory is a result of the [Mandela Effect](https://mandelaeffect.com/about/).

There is not a huge difference between the scenes as described... Hermey does work on the Abominable Snowman's teeth; and the Abominable Snowman does show up at the end, no longer being a threat. There is not, however, any evidence of a version where the Snowman is described as having had a toothache.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_%28TV_special%29#Different_versions) lists details about the various versions that were released; the biggest differences have to do with the addition of a scene showing that Santa visited the island misfit toys.

There is a lot of discussion about this particular example of the Mandela Effect on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MandelaEffect/comments/7jl5oc/rudolph_the_rednosed_reindeer_1964/). So it is not uncommon for people to remember it this way.

Comment: I do not accept your "answer".  Trotting out the Mandela Effect is illegitimate.  If 10,000 people came forward to say they saw the Toothache version, you can just wave your hand and say "Mandela Effect".  That's not proof of anything.  Many people have seen the Toothache version; I know this from the other forum I mentioned originally.  And I would remind you that Wikipedia is not gospel, but the work of sincere but imperfect people.

Comment: For those keeping score, I now have the real answer to my original question.  There has not been any progress getting consensus on this two-version question. The Mandela Effect dodge is still being used.

Comment: Wikipedia tends to be a great source for many answers and sometimes they have their own works cited, which can also be decent official sources. It's true that wikipedia is not always accurate, due to human error, but I think most people do try hard to make it reliable.

Comment: I have not claimed to provide proof that the other version doesn't exist... you can't ever prove something like that. I have simply claimed that there is no evidence (that I can find) to support the idea that it does exist.

Comment: "I remember seeing a version where Hermes murders Santa at the end." Can you prove to me that such a version does not exist? Of course you can't. What i have done is provided a likely explanation for why you remember the version existing.

Comment: I went to Wikepedia's page on some of the versions and then to their source of version. According to youtube video it takes me too, they insist that there could be a new version every year, but do chronicle some of the changes Wikipedia also acknowledges, just not the specific one you are looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXSxy_i2UGE

Comment: Let's leave the question open and see if anyone comes forward and says yeah I saw that.  People, if you did, don't be intimidated by the psychological theory called the Mandela Effect that says you have had a false memory implanted in your brain.

Comment: I looked at the Reddit discussion and noticed that there's really only one guy carrying the argument that the Toothache version doesn't exist.  Most of the others who have a firm opinion say they saw it.  Let's not waste time on either/or.  Both versions have been aired and one has since been obliterated for reasons we don't understand.

Comment: This is textbook Mandela Effect.  I own a set of 1974 Encyclopaedia Brittanica and under the entry of Mandela Effect it cites the confusion of there being two distinct episodes of Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer television special (1964).

Comment: Proves nothing.  They took an example out of the popular culture and took sides.  They didn't research it so that opinion is worth no more than any other.

Comment: If you have some sort of proof that this other version exists, feel free to present it at various places around the internet; several other forums would benefit greatly from such a thing.

Comment: The proof is that everyone and his uncle has seen it.  And they didn't just remember seeing it after hearing the great debate (Mandela Effect victims); they remembered it when asked for the first time with zero prior exposure to the issue.  The real research project should be to unearth what happened to the Toothache version.

Comment: My uncle is blind.  That was a terribly insensitive thing to say.  I wonder if you might actually be "putting us on" about this alternate version.  Having some fun at our expense, hmmm?

Comment: Believe me this is not fun.  Anyway why put this on me?  Dozens of people have said online that they have seen the Toothache version.  Go and look.

Comment: Isn't that the kind of thing that you should create a reference for, and place here, to make your point?

Comment: Yes I realize my commentary is not nearly up to the standards of this site.  I will quit the field here with these comments. (a) anyone can Google "Rudolph reindeer Bumble toothache" and receive reams of info -- I didn't think I needed to compile the links for you (b) this argument is futile until a video of the toothache version is found (c) everybody who still has an open mind get busy and scour your VHS archives.  Thanks for the debate!

Comment: Yes.  But what about this Mandela Effect business?

Comment: Rudolph first aired in 1964.  VCRs did not exist until 1975.  That could explain why the Toothache version cannot be found on video-cassette.

Comment: Also VCR cartridges do not last forever.  The first possible VHS recording would have been 41 years ago.  We don't know how long ago was the last time the Toothache version aired.

Comment: The Toothache version could have been aired without ever being recorded on DVD.

Comment: We depend entirely on someone at NBC or CBS settling this argument.

Comment: As to "what about the Mandela Effect business?"  The M.E. explains how we have a memory of something that didn't happen.  So we don't have to address it at all until it is proved that there is no reasonable possibility that the Toothache version exists.  That has not been done.  The argument that if it existed it would for sure have appeared on VHS or DVD are shown above to be unfounded.

Comment: Comments are not intended for extensive discussion.  If you wish to continue this discussion I suggest doing it on chat.